# Account manager : Android App not appearing under Accounts Tab of Settings,

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, accountmanager

I am trying to dd my application the "Accounts Section" of the settings. So that when the user clicks on Add account , my app name is visible. The complete code can be found [here](https://github.com/abhikmitra/Account_Manager_Demo) 
I have created an authenticator service. This is how my manifest looks like

```
<service android:name=".AuthenticatorService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                   android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>
```

I also created an "authenticator.xml"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:accountType="com.udinic.auth_example"
                       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                       android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                       android:label="testing"
                       android:accountPreferences="@xml/prefs"/>
```

But still I dont see my app under accounts. I am following [this tutorial](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)
 but its not working. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: stuck on the same thing , . . code works for one app , but doesn't work for another @_@

Comment: Hey Abhik, are you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Use a resource string instead of using literal text in label.

**"authenticator.xml"**

```
android:label="@string/some_label"
```